# How to make a vector allocate new (not more) memory

Tags: c++, vector

I have a code with a "matrix" in the format:

`vector < vector<int> > matrix`;

I don't know her sizes: it will be input by the user by the `cin`. I wanted to do something like this:

```
vector<int> row;
while (userInputting)
{
    row.push_back(userInput);
    if (rowIsReady)
    {
        // puts the row in the matrix and allocates a new row to be filled
        matrix.push_back(row);
        **row = new vector<int>();**
    }
}
```

But it's being very difficult to do the intended action of the highlighted line, which usually is simple in other languages. How can I do this or something similar to fill my matrix?

Comment: Why not move `row` into the loop? If it really makes that much of a crucial performance difference, you could do `row = {};`.

Comment: You should allow `std::vector` to handle memory for you. It's one of the best reasons to use `std::vector` over something like an array. `std::vector::push_back` will allocate more memory if it needs it. You don't need to have the memory prepared before you `push_back`

Comment: @chris Moving the row into the loop seems a good option, I will try that.

Comment: @Tas true, but I don't know how much vector<int>s I will put inside the vector<vector<int>>, so I need a dynamic allocation in some way, or, I could use a single vector<int> to determine the matrix, it's an option too, but the first one seems easier.

Comment: C++, as a rule, has value semantics. Pushing `4` to a `vector<int>` just copies the  number 4. Pushing a 1D vector on a 2D vector copies the 1D vector. Don't worry about "dynamic allocations". The vector class manages that for you, even if you have vectors in vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to allocate new memory to write a new row. When `matrix.push_back` is called, its parameter is a copy of row, not row itself. So if you later change the `row` variable, the contents of matrix do not change.

Answer (score 1):

Call the `clear` member function, or `resize( 0 )`, to resize down to 0 again.

You can then use `shrink_to_fit` (in C++11 and later) to make a good attempt at ditching the current buffer, but in the code you sketch that will just incur inefficiency, namely needless dynamic allocations.

An alternative is to assign an emtpy vector, e.g. `row = vector<int>()`, but that will generally have the same effect as `shrink_to_fit`, namely that you get needless dynamic allocations when the buffer size has to be increased again.

Comment: Interesting, but using the `clear` will work if I'm going to put the vector inside a vector of vectors? I don't know much about c++, but, if the vector of vectors stores a reference, then calling the `clear` may also clear the row inside the vector of vectors, or no?

Comment: The `row` vector is copied in the matrix `push_back` operation. C++ containers generally have value semantics: assignment performs deep copy. To get reference semantics you pass (smart) pointers around.